# How to find a sequence of input to drive a system to a certain state?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, modeling, theory, computation

I encountered a problem and would like to ask what type/class of problem it should fall into in terms of algorithm/computing theory. I’d also like to ask if there’s a smart algorithm to solve it instead of searching using the brute force.

The problem is described as follows:

Assuming there are N registers and M instructions. Each instruction performs a certain set of operations over these registers (e.g., n0=n0+1, n2=n3/n4 and n3=n3). And an instruction may require certain pre-condition to be satisfied (e.g., n1>n2+1, n3>0 and no constraints on n4), otherwise, it cannot be applied. The effect of each instruction is deterministic and two instructions may have the same effects on the registers.

Given an initial system state N’ (i.e., the value of each N registers) and a final system state N’’, how to find an instruction sequence that will lead the the system from state N’ to state N’’?

The original problem is more complex than this abstract model and I tried my best to abstract it. So far the only idea I have is to use brute force searching and I feel it is likely to be an NP problem.

Edit:

Thoughts 1:

For a single state, there are some instructions available. By solving some equations, we may derive the basic instructions similar to the real instructions like ADD/MOV/SHR. By operating these basic instructions, it should be easy to change each register's value to the target value. However, there are two problems:

1. This is not a necessary condition for finding a sequence: even if we can't derive such basic instrction sets, we may also be able to drive the system to N''.
2. We still don't have a strategy to navigate the system from state to state. The basic instrction set mentioned above are only valid in a certain state and after some operations, it will be invalidated since the pre-condition of some instructions no longer match.

Comment: For me, it looks like a strange variant of bin packing problem, coupled with a travelling salesman problem. I barely see how it could **NOT** be a NP problem...

Comment: Thanks Wisblade. Can you elaborate on how does my problem fits into these two problems you proposed? In my understanding, after fitting into these two problems, the final solution is still searching different input sequences. Is that right?

Comment: The "bin packing" part is, for me, the various pre-conditions that each instruction has. Think about it as size/weight constraint of the bin packing problem, but instead of having a physical constraint, it's on the register state. Anyway, it grows like a partial permutation, with constraints on some sets. So it's a factorial complexity at least, since instructions can be repeated. Then, you must also match a travelling salesman problem, with a known start (N'), and a known end (N"), with must ALSO match with the previous permutations - so you must apply each permutation set to this graph [TBC]

Comment: So, finally, you have an already complex problem, already considered as NP (find a given sequence between the whole permutations, with "artificially" duplicated elements to match the possibility of having several times the same instruction, coupled with a graph path find... Currently, you didn't spoke about finding the _minimum_ instruction set that solves the problem, but I suppose that it would be only a matter of time - and then the salesman problem. Coupling the two, it should be a NP problem, since both elementary problems are already considered as NP, or NP-like in best cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic problem which might have exponential or polynomial complexity solutions depending on the dataset and the operations:

- solving a Rubik's Cube can be solved in O(n2) operations : [https://3dpancakes.typepad.com/ernie/2010/06/complexity-of-rubiks-cube.html#:~:text=A%20given%20configuration%20of%20the,in%20O(n%C2%B3)%20time](https://3dpancakes.typepad.com/ernie/2010/06/complexity-of-rubiks-cube.html#:%7E:text=A%20given%20configuration%20of%20the,in%20O(n%C2%B3)%20time).
- solving the "Countdown" problem - ie you are given a result, numbers and you need to find an equation using the numbers and + - * / operators leading to this result : seem to be tough (mostly exponential) : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272521048_The_Final_countdown

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks. There are also constraints (pre-conditions on register values)  for each instruction. A instruction can only be executed when its constraints are satisfied. I think in the Rubik's Cube "Countdown" problem, they have no constraints regarding the current state (register values) for each instruction/operation. Any ideas?

Comment: Really this seems too generic.